# Alfresco: Get list of nodes with updated ACL/permission

Tags: alfresco, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I am exploring **Alfresco Web scripts and CMIS API's**, and looking for an API or some way to figure out the nodes whose **ACL/permission** is modified after some specified time/timestamp in Alfresco.

I am able to get nodes with modified metadata using *CMIS QUERY API*, but regarding only ACL/permission modification its not working.

For now, I am crawling all nodes and checking its modification date with respect to earlier/last crawl datetime. This doesn't seem to be a proper approach.

For more details, here is the link of query posted earlier on **alfresco forum**:[Fetch the list of nodes whose permission is updated/modified](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/fetch-list-nodes-whose-permission-updatedmodified-09222015)

Could anyone please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution, using **CMISChangeLog** application, which need to be enabled on Alfresco server. Also, with the help of CMIS 1.1 Atom Api's, the CMIS change log query works fine on both the Alfresco version, 4.x and 5.x.